Does anyone know of a source for the ראם in the Torah (Devarim 33:17) being the same animal as the איל?
I’ve heard it said that it’s the same species as the איל (ram), just at a different age (like an אישה and a נערה).
Other answers to this question Animal R'aim of the midrash are almost certainly not going according to Rashi (Devarim 33:17 he says the Re’em is not a strong animal, and the answers given are either an Aurochs or elephant, both very strong), so perhaps Rashi holds it’s a Ram?
Does anyone know of a source for this?
Note: This question is different from the dupe because it's not asking what the Re'em is but rather looking for a source that states this particular interpretation.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The answers to the dupe disprove this interpretation, thus making the question irrelevant—unless, of course, you have some reason for finding the source other than verifying this interpretation. If that’s the case, you should edit your reason into the question with an acknowledgement of the answers to the dupe. Your question would likely get reopened.

I tried that already pointing out that those answers are not going according to rashi who explicitly says the Re’em is not a strong animal, and being that I have heard pshatim that it’s an איל (albeit without a source) I’m trying to see if perhaps that’s what rashis referring to.

Most likely, the question is stated because of similarity of English word ram and Hebrew ראם. The etymology of the english word is unknown and seems to be indo-european https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ram.

@YDJ I asked the question because I was told this pshat from a big Talmud Chacham and for whatever reason I no longer have access to him to find out the source.
